# javascript clearTimeout problems using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I did 2 countdowns events but I can't stop the setTimeout (countDown) function later using the clearTimeout. This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var lives = 5
var livesmenos1 = "4";
var livesmenos1 = 4;
var countdownfinal = 10;
var t;
var isTimeron = false;
var onelive = "1";
var onelive = 1;

$(".wrongbutton, .wrongbutton2, .wrongbutton3").click(function () {
    $(".countdownfirst").text(livesmenos1)
    livesmenos1--;
    if (livesmenos1 == 0) (livesmenos1 = 0);
    if (livesmenos1 < 2)
        $(".countdownfirst").css({ "color": "990099", "font-size": "380%" });
    if (livesmenos1 < 1)
        $(".lives").attr("src", "images/morelives.gif");
    if (livesmenos1 < 0)
        $("#tableone, #tabletwo").delay(1000).hide(2000);
    if (livesmenos1 < 0)
        $("#tableloser").delay(2000).fadeIn(2500, function countDown() {
            setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
            $("#box").text(countdownfinal + " seconds").css({ "color": "990099" });
            countdownfinal--;
            if (countdownfinal < 1) (countdownfinal = 10);
            if (countdownfinal < 2)
                $(".countdownfirst").text(onelive++);
            if (onelive > 5)
                $(".countdownfirst").text("5");
            if (onelive > 1)
                $("#nextbuttonloser").delay(1000).fadeIn(500).delay(30000);
        });
 });
});
```

then I did the myStopFunction onclick button to start the clearTimeOut function:

```
function myStopFunction()
{
clearTimeout(countDown);
}
```

and it doesn't work. I tried to trigger also using jQuery but again, with no effect. How can i do to stop the setTimeout function named "countDown"?

thanks

Comment: You are not showing where `countDown` is defined, this is very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to stop a specific function from firing in a `Timeout`. The only way is to stop the timeout itself. Every timeout returns an integer value when it is called. Use this value to clear the timeout. Note that it is going to need to be available to the scope of your function

```
var TimeoutHandle;
$(document).ready(function () {
 ...
 TimeoutHandle = setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
 ...
});

function myStopFunction()
{
 clearTimeout(TimeoutHandle);
}
```

Comment: yes. I was trying to create a 30 secs delay to stop the timer itself and create an if stat equal zero but.. yes. thanks